# TFS - Creating a "sandbox" project within a solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

I have a solution with the following structure:

```
> SolutionA
  > ProjectA
    > FolderA
      > FileA
      > FileB
    > FolderB
  > ProjectB
    > FolderC
      > FileC
```

I have a developer who wants to play with some testing scenarios and who only needs to be exposed to `FileA` and `FileC`.  What I would like to do is the following:

```
> SolutionA
  > ProjectA
    > FolderA
      > FileA
      > FileB
    > FolderB
  > ProjectB
    > FolderC
      > FileC 
  > SandboxProject
    > FolderA [link]
      > FileA [link]
    > FolderC [link]
      > FileC [link]
    > FolderSandbox
      > FileSandbox
```

I'd like to add `SandboxProject` to achieve the following:

- Provide the developer access to source-controlled files without exposing him to things he doesn't need to know about - these files aren't independent enough to be in their own projects, but he doesn't need to know about other siblings.  This is both a security (sensitive files) and dev UX concern (don't show more than necessary).
- Provide an easy way to play with the consumers of the linked files (for example - a linked file might be `plugin.js` but he will make his own `Index.cshtml` to consume/test it.  His changes to `plugin.js` will be seen in the original project as it's just a link to a source-controlled file.  Changes to `Index.cshtml` won't impact other projects because it's source-controlled within `SandboxProject` only.

Does Visual Studio / VSTS support this kind of "linking" and isolation?  If so, what steps should be taken to achieve it?  Can I use `Add as link` for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported.

Regarding Add as link, the target files must be downloaded to a machine (can be in a shared folder), also these files need to be accessible. So, I don’t think it meets your requirements.

The better way is that, you can package necessary files/project and publish to VSTS/TFS feed, then developers can add these packages reference.

Note: With this way, the changes to package files won’t affect the source files. But since the developer don’t know about the things of the source files, the changes in “linked” files shouldn’t affect the source files.

More information about vsts/tfs feed, you can refer to: [Package Management in Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/overview).

Comment: I've just tested this "Add as link" and then modified my build to copy linked files.  It works like a charm if I deny read at the root level and then grant read at the project level.  Is what I'm doing somehow actually not doing what I expect?

Comment: @SB2055 Not clear about "without exposing him to things he doesn't need to know about", if you grant permission to developers to access source file(linked file), it is ok.

Comment: `File B` and `Folder B`

Comment: @SB2055 For this scenario, it's ok.